# write xlsx file using openpyxl module in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, export-to-excel, xlrd, openpyxl

I am having trouble writing to excel file using openpyxl module. So far I am able to write this code

```
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
import datetime

header = [u'Name', u'Email', u'Mobile', u'Current location',]
new_data = [
               [u'name1', u'email1@yahoo.com', 9929283421.0, u'xxxx'], 
               [u'name2', u'email2@xyz.com', 9994191988.0, u'xxxx']
           ]
wb = Workbook()
cur_date = str(datetime.date.today())
log_file = "%s/%s_%s_errorlog.xlsx" % (settings.MEDIA_ROOT,
                                       os.path.splitext(file_name)[0], 
                                       cur_date)
log_csv = wb.worksheets[0]

for i in range(1, len(header) + 1):
    log_csv.cell(row = 1 ,column = i).value = header[i - 1]

wb.save(log_file)

error_count = 0
for each_row in new_data:
    error_count += 1
    for i in range(1, len(each_row) + 1):
        log_csv.cell(row = error_count ,column = i).value = each_row[i - 1]

wb.save(log)
```

File is created, but it is corrupted and I am not able to open it with the excel file reader (LibreOffice) provided by the OS (ubuntu). Also the contents of the file are not readable. Not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: Why are you trying to write the coordinates rather than using `ws.append()`?

Creating a range over a sequence is poor Python. Use `enumerate(seq)` instead.

Answer (score 10):

```
from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook

header = [u'Name', u'Email', u'Mobile', u'Current location',]
new_data = [[u'name1', u'email1@yahoo.com', 9929283421.0, u'xxxx'], 
            [u'name2', u'email2@xyz.com', 9994191988.0, u'xxxx']]

wb = Workbook()

dest_filename = 'empty_book.xlsx'

ws1 = wb.active

ws1.title = "range names"

ws1.append(header)

for row in new_data:
    ws1.append(row)

wb.save(filename = dest_filename)
```

I am able to write the content to xlsx like above.

Comment: `for row in new_data:
    ws.append(row)`

Comment: Yes. I should have used that in my answer. Edited. :)